# How to assign correlative numbers to rows only using SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following table in an Oracle database:

```
InvoiceNumber InvoiceDate InvoiceCorrelative
------------- ----------- ------------------
          123  02-03-2009                  0
          124  02-03-2009                  0
          125  02-04-2009                  0
          126  02-04-2009                  0
          127  02-04-2009                  0
          128  02-05-2009                  0
          129  02-06-2009                  0
          130  02-06-2009                  0
          ...         ...                ...
```

And I want to set a value for the `InvoiceCorrelative` column in every row in order to have a sequence of numbers starting at 1 for each date. In the example above I want the table to look like this:

```
InvoiceNumber InvoiceDate InvoiceCorrelative
------------- ----------- ------------------
          123  02-03-2009                  1
          124  02-03-2009                  2
          125  02-04-2009                  1
          126  02-04-2009                  2
          127  02-04-2009                  3
          128  02-05-2009                  1
          129  02-06-2009                  1
          130  02-06-2009                  2
          ...         ...                ...
```

Is it possible to do it **only using SQL statements**?. I've been playing with rownum but didn't get anywhere.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY InvoiceDate ORDER BY InvoiceNumber)
```

Comment: This will work with MSSQL but looking at the tag, the asker is using Oracle.

Comment: Quick look says ROW_NUMBER() is supported in Oracle 10g+, but DENSE_RANK is 9i: http://techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/dense_rank.php

Comment: @Josh Smeaton: I think Oracle invented analytic functions and Microsoft copied them  @OMG Ponies: interesting link!

Comment: 9i had the RANK(), DENSE_RANK(), and ROW_NUMBER() analytic functions.  The only difference between the three are how they handle ties.  ROW_NUMBER returns a unique value for each row, arbitrarily breaking ties.  RANK gives ties the same value and skips subsequent values, as you would do in an athletic competition.  If there is a tie for first, the next competitor gets third place.  DENSE_RANK eliminates the gaps while giving ties the same value so that if there is a tie for first the next row gets a value of 2.

Answer (score 5):

Using Standard SQL,

```
  Update TableName T Set
    InvoiceCorrelative = 
     (Select Count(*) From TableName 
      Where InvoiceDate = T.InvoiceDate
        And InvoiceNumber <= T.InvoiceNumber)
```

Comment: This answer is much better than accepted one. It works perfectly not looking at what db you use. Just pure SQL!